# Calculating average for each individual or not?

Tags: correlation, mean, descriptive-statistics, aggregation

I have a question about how I should organize my data before doing some statistical analyses.

In my data, I have a sample of rats for which the level of tear stains and body lesions is measured. They are both scored on a scale from 0 to 2. For these I would like to make a Spearman correlation test to see if the two variables are associated. Each rat has been measured multiple times for both variables.

My question is whether I should first aggregate the data at individual level by taking the average of the measures for each individual before making the test, or if this is not necessary. Would this affect the result of the test?

Answer (score 0):

Most tests of association assume that your observations are independently distributed from one another. If you take the means of the measurements for each individual before conducting the test, this assumption will hold. However, if you do not take the mean and report individual measurements, there will be an unnatural level of grouping in your data between measurements from the same individual, and you will end up with p-values that are too small.

Mixed models (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model) can be used if you want to account for associations within individuals when conducting a test.